# MODx установка снипета на MODx Evolution

Tags: modx

Здраствуйте,  у меня следущая проблема я скачал  из сайта файл со снипетом Formit, у меня стоит MODx Evolution мне нужно установить этот снипет. Я раньше не сталкивался с этим прозьба помочь и описать как это нужно делать в  MODx Evolution , очень надо. Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

Formit, сниппет для MODX Revolution. Для форм обратной связи в MODX Evolution используйте сниппет eForm

Comment: А как в MODX Evolution сделать такое же вспливающие окошко как в MODX Revolution? Сори я только учусь...спасибо зарание!

Comment: покажите картинкой окошко которое вы хотите сделать и что вы именно от этого окошка хочете.

Comment: "Всплывающее окошко" не зависит от MODX, это зависит от тех средств js и css которые Вы будете использовать. Точнее по этому вопросу консультировать я не готов.
Рекомендую для изучения этой замечательной системы: хорошие уроки по созданию сайтов на MODX Evolution на сайте у Ефимова - http://efimov.ws а также много подсказок на http://community.modx-cms.ru/ и http://modx.im/
Успехов!

Comment: Я готов прокомментировать если будет адекватный вопрос.

Comment: @binliz я уже создал форму которую мне нужно с помощью сниппета eform но я не знаю как сделать чтобы эта форма при нажатии например кнопки выскакивала как всплывающие окошко и там уже можна было отправлять даные.... Вот таккая вот проблема подскажите кто как это можна реализовать. Спасибо!

Comment: всплываюшее окошо делается следующим образом: вы создаете div в этот div вставляете форму, в стиле ему присваиваете position:absolute; и display: hide; на кнопку вешаете обработчик события click в котором делаете display:block; в общем где-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/pB8d6/

Comment: сори я уже розобрался=)